# Threading issues just showed up site wide three weeks ago

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, entity-framework, asynchronous, azure-web-app-service

B"H

I have an asp.net MVC codebase that has been working fine for close to a **decade**.
We've been working on it constantly adding features, etc.

We upgraded to Asp.net 5 about two years ago. No major upgrades since then. We are running in Web Applications in Azure.

Everything has been running fine.
Now, three weeks ago, things that have worked fine for years are starting to throw threading related issues.

"The wait operation timed out" in many actions.
"open datareader associated with this command"
"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed"
"Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context"

I am going through and fixing each issue. But we are talking about multiple projects with thousands and thousands of lines of code. What could have caused them all to start acting up at once?

Comment: I would recommend you enable diagnostic logging for your azure web app to troubleshoot this issue. Details you could follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Comment: This is a great tool, and one of many that I am using to track down every bug that surfaced. But they all have one root - Something changed in the way asynchronous tasks are being handled in my websites. Hundreds of bugs that surfaced all at once in live production code. It will take me a bit of time to track down each one. The question is what made this happen? Either a setting was changed in Azure, or a Nuget package was updated. The most likely culprit would be something in the Asp.net stack.

Comment: If you can, try to track the System Updates that occurred in your host environment.